# Why can't I print the updated score?

Tags: qt, qml

I  have the score defined as below to be printed on screen

```
property int score: 0

Text {
    id: score1
    text: "Score: "+ score
    anchors.bottom: grid.top
    font.pointSize: 20
    color: "red"
}
```

and this list model to access and change square colors and text values in the grid

```
property variant colorArray: ["cyan","red","white"]
ListModel {
    id: dummyModel

    ListElement {
        squareColor: "white"
        txt: 0
    }
    ListElement {
        squareColor: "white"
        txt: 0
    }
    ListElement {
        squareColor: "white"
        txt: 0
    }
    ListElement {
        squareColor: "white"
        txt: 0
    }
}

Timer { 
    // to change square colors randomly
    id: alfa
    interval: 2000; running: true; repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        for (var i=0;i<dummyModel.count;i++) {                
            dummyModel.setProperty(i,"squareColor",colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)])
        }
    }
}

Timer { 
    // to change score values in grid element randomly
    id: beta
    interval: 2000; running: true; repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        for (var i=0;i<dummyModel.count;i++) {
            var sc = Math.floor(Math.random()*20) // random value from 0 to 20
            dummyModel.setProperty(i,"txt",sc) // score in each square
        }
    }
}
```

and this grid contains colored squares, when a square is clicked and color is cyan score should be updated by the number in the text field tttt

```
Grid{
    id: grid
    rows: 2
    columns:2
    spacing: 5
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Repeater{
        id: gridRect
        model: dummyModel // from a list element model 
        Rectangle{
            id: rect
            width: 50
            height: width
            color: "cyan" 
            radius: 10
            Text {
                id: tttt
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: "lightBlue"
                text : txt
            }
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    if (rect.color == "cyan")
                        score = score + tttt.text
                    else if (rect.color == "red")
                        score = score - tttt.text
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but score can't be updated on click instead I get this error/warning:

```
<Unknown File>: Can't assign to existing role 'txt' of different type [Number -> String]
```

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Text component can receive any type of data: string, number, etc. and try to convert it to string, in your case when you use txt.text you are getting that converted string. So there are 2 solutions convert the string to number, or better not use the value of the Text component but the property of the model:

```
// ...
Rectangle{
    id: rect
    width: 50
    height: width
    color: model.squareColor
    radius: 10
    Text {
        id: tttt
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "lightBlue"
        text : model.txt
    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (model.squareColor === "cyan")
                score = score + model.txt
            else if (model.squareColor === "red")
                score = score - model.txt
        }
    }
}
// ...
```